# How come my program doesn't prompt for the end value? [C]

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    {
        // TODO: Prompt for start size
        int s;
        do
        {
            s = get_int("Starting_value: ");
        } while (s < 9);
        return s;
    }
    // TODO: Prompt for end size
    int e; 
    do 
    {
        e = get_int("End_value: ");
    } while ("e < s");
    return e;
    // TODO: Calculate number of years until we reach threshold
        
    // TODO: Print number of years
}
```

I was wondering why my program doesn't prompt me for the end value when I run it, I'm new to programming so the answer might just be obvious. I've tried renaming the variables but that didn't work. The first part of the program works as intended, where it prompts for the starting size, just it doesn't prompt for end size. Thanks.

Comment: Do basic debugging. Use a debugger and/or even simple debug print statements. What happens when `return s;` is run? Also, `while ("e < s");` Why have you used a string for the condition?

Comment: I agree with the other commenter. Put in printf statements between lines and see what it tells you.

Comment: Because you return (and exit) right after accepting input for `s`.  You should use conventional and consistent indentation and braces (`{...}`), both because it will make the error rather obvious, but also because you are asking others to read your code, and you are making it unnecessarily difficult by poor formatting.

Comment: There's no return from a `return` statement (if you see what I mean). Once that has been executed, the module/function it is in is over.

Comment: @Clifford what would conventional and consistent formatting look like?

Comment: For a do-while loop, put `while` on the same line as the `}` so it's clear that it's part of the loop before it, not an empty `while` loop after.

Comment: @JeremyGuo well you have since edited to fix, so now you know.  That highlights the unconditional block ending in return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best advice I can provide here is that you don't need to use `return` at all for this piece of code.

> You are assigning the requested integers to variables `s` and `e`,
> and so you can print them out later.

Once something is returned, the function ends right there and then, and since you only have one `main` function, your whole program ends as soon as something is returned.